# Django multi stage form saves all fields except for selection fields

Tags: python, django

I have a multistage form. All fields save successfully but not select fields.

My code related to the select field:

Forms.py

```
class StepFive(StepFour):
    dob = forms.DateField(
        label="Date of birth?",
        required=False,
    )

    year = forms.ChoiceField(
        label="Year",
        choices=YEAR,
    )

    usage = forms.ChoiceField(
        label="Usage",
        required=True,
        choices=USAGE,
        widget=forms.RadioSelect,
    )
    
    def clean_year(self):
        year = self.cleaned_data["year"]
        usage = self.cleaned_data["usage"] = "True"
        if not usage:
            dob = self.cleaned_data.get("dob", date.today())
            earliest_year = dob.year + 18
            if int(year) <= earliest_year:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    "Invalid Year", code="invalid"
                )
        return year
```

view.py

```
@require_http_methods(["POST"])
def step5(request):
    form = forms.StepFive(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        status = 200
    else:
        status = 400
    return render(
        request,
        "step5.html",
        context={
            "form": form,
        },
        status=status,
    )
```

The html product on the browser

```
<select class="form-control " name="year" id="id_year" aria-describedby="id_year-help" cursorshover="true">
            
                
                <option value="2021">2021</option>
                <option value="2020">2020</option>
                 ... etc ...
</select>
```

All the fields from the same step get saved except for the select value.

I can see the form in the `from.cleaned` data but it gets reset when I click next.

Comment: can add your model you are saing, the whole form and the view where you are trying to save the data?

Comment: I can't add the all the code, but I have updated the code above.